# How to wipe everything off your Facebook wall?

Tags: facebook, status

I tried some [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3863/) scripting but that didn't go very well as I couldn't write a script to do the job. Also, I imagine it would take ages to delete everything this way even if I made a good enough script.

Is there a method that actually works?

Comment: Hypothetically ... if there is a way (which most likely there is but it would be easier to just delete your account or apply privacy groups)... Do you not think that someone at Facebook will flag your account ? Maybe if you can explain your reasoning then it would be clearer.

Comment: I would add, as a general contribution for those who may come across this, that the fluid nature of Facebook and, by extension, its privacy architecture, makes simply "protecting" things a potentially dangerous way of hiding things. An update to the privacy system or a bug introduced somewhere along the way may make things suddenly visible that you never expected to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the graph script which is described perfectly on: `http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api`

Just for you to know, there to acces your, or other profiles (walls from people call the following:
`https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=xxx`x

Then after you list the ids of the comments you can call for each one of those the issuing a POST request to:
 `https://graph.facebook.com/COMMENT_ID?method=delete.`

Comment: This is a hypothetical question, but would that delete everything that you have posted on your wall or EVERYTHING on the wall?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Comment: Piers question asks whether that method will delete only his own posts (everything you have posted on your wall) or whether it will delete his own posts and posts from his friends to his wall (EVERYTHING).