# Delete old Facebook wall posts

Tags: facebook, security, privacy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Script or App to remove own Facebook status updates](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8989/script-or-app-to-remove-own-facebook-status-updates)

> **Related:**
>   [How to delete all Facebook posts/comments older than 1 year?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12937/how-to-delete-all-facebook-posts-comments-older-than-1-year)
>   [How can I delete all Facebook status entries older than a week old?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15809/how-can-i-delete-all-facebook-status-entries-older-than-a-week-old)
>   [How to wipe out everything from your Facebook wall?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10136/how-to-wipe-out-everything-from-your-facebook-wall)

I'm looking for a way to way to delete all my posts, comments etc on my Facebook wall.

My concern is with information security, I want to limit how much information is available at any point.

I can see that Facebook allows you to hide your wall, however the information is still there against your account.

Any ideas?

Comment: what would you like done with this? http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/819/question-closed-without-consultation-unhappy-with-linked-question-answers